# In AWS nested security group works for load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have problem with the nested security groups (instead of adding CIDR I adding the security id into another security group as rule) to allow the traffic on the AWS load-balancer.

like we have 2 security group one with public ip's and another with private ip's which is open for all traffic. To access the web page I need add some customs ip's including public ip security group and private ip security group. Here I created a new security group by adding the custom ip's , private ip security group ID and public Security group ID by opening the ports 80 and 443. If I give the IP's directly i able to access the web page. But, I am Unable to access the web page by using Security ID. what can i do in this situation?

Private IP's security group:

[image]

Public Ip's security group:

[image]

By add the above security group id's and added some custom Ip's into this security group created this security group. I try to use this security group on UI load-balance to access the UI. But I am not able to access the UI:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it is hard to understand your configuration from the information given. Could you please explain a it a little clearer, perhaps by showing the security group configurations? Are both security groups associated with the Load Balancer? Could you please clarify what scenario works and what scenario does _not_ work?

Comment: thanks for response i added the snapshots of my security group  for more clear...

Comment: Could you please clarify your configuration? You mention a Load Balancer. Are these security groups on the Load Balancer? What groups are in the instance(s)? Can you clarify what configuration works and what configuration doesn't work? Please explain as much as you can, so we can understand exactly what you have.

Comment: Yes these security groups we are adding on top of  load balancer.  when i am adding the IP's instead of security group ID into to the security group 3 in that case i am able to access the UI web page, but when i am adding the "Public and private" Security group ID's  instead of IP's into the 3rd  Security groups of not able to access the UI web page..

Comment: Your Private IP addresses appear to be in `/16` and `/19` ranges. This is a bit strange, because a whole VPC can't be bigger than `/16` (I think). Are these from peered VPCs? A private IP address can only be referenced if it is in the same VPC or in a peered VPC.

Comment: Its on same VPC